# Classifications of Nearly Kaehler manifolds with constant holomorfic curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I read that six dimmensional sphere is only nearly Kaehler, not Kaehler manifolds which has constant holomorfic sectional curvature. Can someone help me to find this paper which has a proof of this - A. Gray: Classification des vartetSs approximativement kahleriennes de courbure sectionelle
holomorphe constante, C R. Acad. Sci. Paris 279 (1974), 797—799... Gray cited this in one his work, but i can't find this paper.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the *Comptes Rendus* have been digitized and are available on the website of the [French national library](http://gallica.bnf.fr/). Even so it can take a little digging to find specific items. This one is available [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6226936t); use the navigation bar at the bottom to pick out page 797.

Comment: Thank you very much :)